# Django Rest Framework:RecursionError at /profile/ maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have completed my project on social networking and setting an option for logout 
MeanWhile I came across django-rest-auth app and tried to use it but later choose to do it by myself so, deleted it from settings.py and urls.py and used "pip uninstall django-rest-auth" to clear out things.
Now when i try to create a new user It gives me this error:

RecursionError at /profile/
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    friends_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='profile_pics/',blank=False,null=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.user.username,)
```

views.py:

```
class UserCreateAPIViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    """"A View which handles  Creating  and Updating User Profile"""
    serializer_class = UserProfileCreateSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)

    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('username','email',)
```

urls.py:

```
  router.register(r'profile',views.UserCreateAPIViewSet)
```

serializers.py:

```
class UserProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     """"A serializer for user data request"""
     location = serializers.CharField(source='profile.location')
     friends_count = serializers.IntegerField(source='profile.friends_count',read_only=True)
     profile_pic = serializers.FileField(source='profile.profile_pic',allow_empty_file=True,allow_null=True)


     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = (
            'pk',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'location',
            'friends_count',
            'profile_pic',
         )
         extra_kwargs = {
        'password':{'write_only':True},
        'friends_count':{'read_only':True},
    }

    def create(self, validated_data):
    """"Create and return a new User"""


        user = User(
        email = validated_data['email'],
        username = validated_data['username']
        )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])

        user.save()

        return user
```

Comment: Can you provide traceback of the error?

Comment: I've solved it !!! Thank your for response!!!!

Comment: Can you provide the solution? @DilipKrishna

Comment: I'll give you my project link , you can look into that.
If you want anything specific you can ask me about it.
Link: https://github.com/Dilip23/ViredApp-Backend
@ŠarūnasAžna

Comment: I found a problem, and a pseudo solution for my case. Problem - recursion was appearing while trying to login with basic auth. So i just blocked basic auth since we have and prefer other auth methods. But this is like giving Tranquilizer to depressed people...
I found out that error occurs on axes.backends.AxesModelBackend.autheticate method, and also other autheticators (Axes must be first according to docs) when i removed Axes. So problem is that for some reason autheticator cannot set request.user with its user and password.
Thanks for the link, i will take a look ;)

Comment: I hope but I am not sure it might be problem with model being used inside serializer.  Yeah,Ping me! If you need anything. And your Welcome.